# Не удаляется элемент jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$(".inf_cl").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().slideUp(500);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).parent().delay(500).remove();
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
```

Привет. Никак не могу понять, почему после слайдапа этот элемент не удаляется. Вроде верно все сделал... Помогите плиз)

Comment: Тогда вопрос ответный - а как вы вычислили, что он не удаляется?

Comment: ПКМ - просмотр кода элемента

Comment: По идее, после slideUp, элемент даже виден не должен быть. И второе,
зачем такой многоходовое действие? Почему не убирать его коллбэком?

Comment: Нет, я понимаю, что он не виден) Мне нужно его именно удалить. Вариант ниже идеален. Я просто не знал, что еще и функцию после выполнения слайдапа сделать

Comment: Я про то и говорил. Но вы, сударь, меня удивили, что до сих пор не знаете, что 99% методов jQuery дают возможность использовать коллбэк-функции ))

Comment: Так это.. начинающий в jQuery типа я :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

внутри

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).parent().delay(500).remove();
}, 500);
```

`this` не указывает на `$(".inf_cl")`

попробуйте

```
var elem = $(this).parent();
elem.slideUp(500, function(){
    elem.remove();
});
return false;
```

- [.slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)